# c++ vectors, pointers, etc

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm working on some basic collision detection homework. I have a vector that contains a bunch of sphere objects that have members for radius, position, velocity, etc. I've narrowed down my problem to the following code.

This is the code I was given that works. For each sphere in the vector spheres, it checks all the other spheres in vector spheres for collision.

```
// Do the physics simulation
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < spheres.size(); i++ )
{   
    spheres[i].computeForces(gravity, air_friction, walls, spheres);
}
```

which refers to this function: (the last argument is a vector of spheres)

```
// Compute all the forces between a sphere and the walls and other spheres and gravity and drag.
void computeForces(Vec3d gravity, double dragConstant, plane walls[6], std::vector< sphere > & spheres)
{
    clearForce();
    accumulateGravity( gravity );
    accumulateDrag( dragConstant );
    // Now check for collisions with the box walls
    for ( int j = 0; j < 6; j++ )
        accumulatePlaneContact(walls[j]);

    //Check for collisions with external spheres in the environment
    for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < spheres.size(); j++ )
        if ( this != &spheres[j] ) // Don't collide with yourself
            accumulateSphereContact( spheres[j] );
}
```

I modified things so that I don't have to check every sphere against the others, but just compare one at a time, and this doesn't work.

```
// Do the physics simulation
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < spheres.size(); i++ )
{
            //Here I can choose which spheres to test
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < spheres.size(); j++)
    {
    spheres[i].computeForce(gravity, air_friction, walls, spheres[j]);
    }
}
```

with this function: (the last argument is a single sphere)

```
void computeForce(Vec3d gravity, double dragConstant, plane walls[6], sphere & s)
{
    clearForce();
    accumulateGravity( gravity );
    accumulateDrag( dragConstant );
    for ( int j = 0; j < 6; j++ )
    {
        accumulatePlaneContact(walls[j]);
    }
    if (this != &s)
    {
        accumulateSphereContact(s);
    }
}
```

Running through in debug mode, it runs fine and seem to enter all the functions correctly and do computations, but it's like the forces don't actually get saved to the sphere objects. I get spheres passing through each other. (collisions with walls, gravity, and drag all work fine).

What's the difference? My first guess is that it has to do with. I've also tried this using an unordered_map instead of vector with the same resulting behavior.

Comment: Are you making a new vector of spheres in your for loop?

Comment: No. There is only one vector<sphere> spheres.

Comment: Just a general comment on your C++ coding.  It is lacking and its going to cause you liabilities down the road.  Things like that if in  a for loop you pay on every iteration even though you know it only gets hit once.  There are several more C++ problems that are there but the one I mentioned is the most concrete.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of some of the issues. If you really want to be appalled, I'll send you the rest of the code my professor provided for this project. I'm an engineering student, he's a CS faculty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in the first case, `computeForces()`, which includes a call to `clearForce()`, was called only once on each sphere. In your modified case, you're calling `computeForce()` once for each partner sphere, and each of these calls does `clearForce()`. I guess that's the problem.

Comment: Bingo. Kicking myself for that one.